# Multible clicks on taskswitcher to close all open apps

Tags: multitasking

I'm running Android 5.0 on my Nexus 5.
Everytime I close all apps in the taskswitcher and close and open the taskswitcher again, there are still some apps open, why is it and can I turn it off/do I want to turn it off?

Thanks

Josef

Comment: That depends on what you're trying to achieve by closing all apps. There's normally no need to do this.

Comment: Apps randomly appearing in recents is a [known bug](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/11/17/lollipops-app-switcher-has-a-bug-that-shows-random-cards-after-youve-cleared-them-all/) and [has been reported to AOSP](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79205&q=recents&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars). The only real option now is to wait for a fix.